# what is facebox and thickbox

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain facebox and thickbox, what's the difference between the two and which do you prefer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

They just have different ways of styling the pop up. Both support images and ajax. Thickbox supports iframes. I would suggest thickbox. It's easy to implement, the style isn't that of what Facebook has already created, and it has support for different kind of content, more so than Facebox. I use http://fancybox.net/ myself. It's very slick, very easy to implement, and has a very flexible API.